# Storing openssl file digest as shell variable?

Tags: bash, openssl, solaris

I am executing the below command in bash

```
filehash=`openssl dgst -sha1 $filename`
```

When I echo $filehash

I get this

> SHA1(myfile.csv)=
> bac9c755bac9709fa8966831d1731dff07e28e6c

How do I only get the hash value stored and not the rest of the string i.e.

> bac9c755bac9709fa8966831d1731dff07e28e6c

Comment: You can pipe to awk|sed
to filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through `sed`,

```
filehash=`openssl dgst -sha1 $filename | sed 's/^.*= //'`
```

It removes all the characters upto the `=`(equal symbol followed by a space).

Comment: Also I realised I can use another tool called "mac" instead of openssl.

Answer (score 3):

In a lot of ways with pure Bash, e. g. by truncating string from start up to last space:

```
filehash="$(openssl dgst -sha1 "$filename")"
filehash="${filehash##* }"
```

or using possibility to obtain reverse (`-r`) notation from `openssl`:

```
read filehash __ < <(openssl dgst -sha1 -r "$filename")
```

Obviously `awk`, `sed` or any other external utility is overkill here. And please note quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Either with sed or awk (if you have them installed):

```
hash=$(echo $filehash | awk -F '=' '{ print $2 }')
```

for example.