# Bash curl sign hmac

Tags: bash, rest, api, curl

I'm trying to use the Bittrex API. The only example provided is the following. I'm not even sure what language this is. I'm trying to replicate this in bash. Full API detail is located here https://bittrex.com/Home/Api

```
$apikey='xxx';
$apisecret='xxx';
$nonce=time();
$uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
$sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
$ch = curl_init($uri);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('apisign:'.$sign));
$execResult = curl_exec($ch);
$obj = json_decode($execResult);
```

I have tried several things but here is the latest I tried.

```
#Bash
apikey="mykey"
secret="mysecret"
nonce=`date +%s`
uri="https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey=$apikey&nonce=$nonce"
apisig=`echo -n "$uri" | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac "$secret"`

curl -sG https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?nonce="$nonce"&apikey="$apikey"&apisig="$apisig"
```

I get "{"success":false,"message":"APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}"

Comment: You probably have to replace `apikey="mykey"` with an actual API key.

Comment: In my actual script I have the full key, I didn't want to post it here.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to makes sure.

Comment: I appreciate you looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're missing are:

- escaping `&` in query string
- passing digest as header rather than parameter

So the code that worked for me is:

```
#!/bin/bash

apikey="mykey"
secret="mysecret"
nonce=`date +%s`
uri="https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/market/getopenorders?apikey=$apikey&nonce=$nonce"
apisig=`printf %s "$uri" | openssl dgst -sha512 -hmac "$secret"| sed 's/^.*= //'`

curl -sG $uri --header "apisign: $apisig"
```

Comment: Also, I added stripping `openssl` output as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261984/storing-openssl-file-digest-as-shell-variable).

Comment: Getting closer but still get "{"success":false,"message":"INVALID_SIGNATURE","result":null}".

Comment: I'm not 100% sure the structure of the uri, that was my best guess.

Comment: Right, it's probably because I forgot to enclose the header in quotes like so: `--header "\"apisign: $apisig\""`

Comment: I think it took a step back "success":false,"message":"APISIGN_NOT_PROVIDED","result":null}"

Comment: Man, you got me so close. Mind editing to remove the "\" to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hope you dont mind I edited your post, I changed echo to printf and it works perfectly. Thanks for you help.